# Immutable NSDictionary with deeply nested hierarchy: change a value for a key?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, immutability

If I have an immutable NSDictionary with nested hierarchy, from a JSON string, what is the easiest way to change a value for a key that is deeply nested in the hierarchy?

For example, I have a dictionary, and the value for "key1" is an array, inside the array, each element is a dictionary, and inside each dictionary, there is a value for key "key2", now I want to change the value for "key2", since the whole data structure is immutable, which makes it difficult, should I duplicate this data structure with mutable collection so that I can change that value, this seems to have a lot of overhead, but this is the only way that came into my mind.

Comment: Did you try type casting that specific dictionary alone and then to change the value for key2?

Comment: @ACB Then I need to cast all its super-dictionaries/arrays to be mutable, so if I have `["key1":({"key2":"value2"}...)]` then in order to cast `{"key2":"value2"}` to be mutable I need to also case it upper level dictionary to be mutable

Comment: I dont think that is needed. What happens if you just try to do this alone? Did you check that?

Comment: @ACB I can try, but how do I cast an immutable dictionary to a mutable one? using `[NSMutableDictionary initWithDictionary:]`? Then it will **copy** all the keys/values in the original dictionary, so that even if I change the value in the mutable one, the original one is not changed.

Comment: Some thing like `[(NSMutableDictionary *)dict setValue...`

Comment: @ACB if it is an `NSDictionary`, how can you cast it into `NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not totally sure, but i think you'll have to pass everyone of your dictionary and array to a mutable one.

It depends if you want to still have a immutable structure after the change or if it doesn't matter if it's still mutable after it.

if you want to stay immutable after the change, then you'll have to use temp variable for mutable dict and array.

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:rootImmutableDict];

NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[rootImmutableDict objectForKey:@"key1"]];

NSMutableDictionary* valueDict = [NSMutableDictionart dictionaryWithDictionary:[mutableArray objectAtIndex:idx]];

[valueDict setObject:newValueObject forKey:@"key2"];

[rootImmutableDict release];
rootImmutableDict = nil;
rootImmutableDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:rootDict];
```

if it doesn't matter for you if it's mutable, then you'd have to make it mutable when retrieving it from the JSON by using a temp immutable structure and make it mutable permanently.

i hope it'll be helpfull to you.

Comment: Actually I need a way to do it for any depth, the example one only has two, but looks like I need to make super collections of the one I need to change to be mutable anyway, so I'll pick yours as the answer.

Comment: The answer by Martin R is *much* easier than this one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is an acceptable alternative for you, but you can create the dictionary from the JSON string with the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option, which creates all arrays and dictionaries as mutable objects.